# Certificates per cluster or certificate per service provider?

Tags: ssl, kubernetes, ssl-certificate

We have service provider that takes a request and creates cluster of elastic search.

What is the best practice to issue ssl certificate ?
1. Should we issue certificate per cluster ?
2. or One cluster for my service provider should be enough which will be used to access clusters ?

I am assuming issuing new certificate while creating cluster is better.

Please provide me the input.

Also, inside the cluster, do I really need to enable ssl so that pods talk to each other passing certificate ?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you should definitely use TLS to encrypt network traffic to, from, and within your Elasticsearch clusters run on shared and managed K8S version (GKE).

Additionally I would opt for a maximum separation of customer spaces with:

- Kubernetes namespaces
- namespaced serviceaccounts/rolebindings

  and even PD-SSD based volumes with [customer supplied encryption](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/disks/customer-supplied-encryption) keys

I'm not sure if you are aware of existence of '[Elastic Cloud on Kubernetes](https://www.elastic.co/blog/introducing-elastic-cloud-on-kubernetes-the-elasticsearch-operator-and-beyond)' (ECK) - it applies Kubernetes Operator pattern for running and operating Elasticsearch clusters on your own K8S cluster in GCP. Treat it also like a collection of a best practices for running Elasticsearch cluster in most secure way, [here](https://github.com/elastic/cloud-on-k8s/blob/master/docs/k8s-quickstart.asciidoc) is a quick start tutorial.